# logo not showing up on Raspberry pi

Tags: pygame

I am working on a project, but the set icon does not show up.
I program on a Raspberry pi, but non of the icons show up, not even the pygame logo. So i wonderd if i coud fix it, but i dont know how.

Here is the code that i use:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
width, height = 200,200
logo = pygame.image.load("CC-logo.png")
GameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("CC",logo)
pygame.display.set_icon(logo)
pygame.display.update()
```

Btw,here is the logo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu6Zq.png

Comment: What is the size of the image?

Comment: As you can see if you click on the link, the image is 32x32 and is a png

Comment: Have you tried using `.convert_alpha()`? You should also see if it finds the current image.

Comment: I tried it by adding the line: logo = `logo.convert_alpha()` and it did not work

Comment: Ah, I was assuming something else but now that I have the means to reproduce the script I found the issue. Made an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
pygame.display.set_caption("CC", logo)
```

`set_caption()` does not take two arguments, just one. So removing the `logo` argument from the function parameters will fix it, and prevent python from throwing an exception. So simply:

```
pygame.display.set_caption("CC")
pygame.display.set_icon(logo)
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work. I work on Raspbian, where the logo of the pygame window always a clean 3:4 window, even with the pygame games library it does that.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I quitted programming python for a few days, rebooted the program and somehow it worked! The program used the code from Pygasm.